# custom validation for uniq_workers trouble with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a custom validation. What I should rewrite.
I want to check on the uniqueness of workers in the current day.

Here's my code:

## crew_worker.rb

```
class CrewWorker < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :crew
  belongs_to :worker
validate :uniq_worker_in_scope_of_day, if: -> obj { obj.new_record? && obj.crew.present? && obj.worker.present? }, on: :create


private

  def uniq_worker_in_scope_of_day
    assignment = crew.assignment #Assignment entity
    crews_leader_ids = assignment.crews.map(&:leader_id) #[1,1]
    active_worker_ids = assignment.worker_ids #[9,1]
    workers = active_worker_ids - crews_leader_ids [9]
    if workers.include?(worker.id) # workers = [9], worker.id = 1
      errors.add(:base, 'has been already assigned at current day')
    end
  end
 end
```

## crew.rb

```
class Crew < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assignment, inverse_of: :crews
end
```

## assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :crews, ->{ order(created_at: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :assignment
  has_many :crew_workers, through: :crews, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :workers, through: :crew_workers
  has_many :assignment_items, through: :crews, dependent: :destroy
end
```

but this validation works 2 times. and the next laps it returns:

```
#first_lap:
workers = [9]
worker.id = 1

#second_lap:
workers = [9]
worker.id = 9
```

Why in the second laps it's return 9 and 9, not a 9 and 1.
p.s in the comment's it what debugger return.

Comment: It will be better if you define associations defined and model name in which above validation working

Comment: Another approach could be to create a unique index on the combination of the date and worker_id so the database takes care of the constraint.

Comment: Can you explain more detail about your thing? Please